# Problems to create ssh tunnel from Windows to Ubuntu with VNC

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, vnc, tunnel

I have Windows (client) and Linux (server).
I want to have a VNC access over ssh to Linux.
I use Port 2222 as ssh port.

I managed to install the ssh and login to the linux server via ssh using public key without password.
I have tried several configurations via windows console, which also work:

```
ssh -l user -L 5901:localhost:5901 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p2222
```

OR

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p2222
```

But when I try to go in via VNC viewer (Windows) with `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5901`, **the connection is interrupted.**

I change the default "sshd_config" to:

```
AllowTcpForwarding local

X11Forwarding yes
```

Port 2222 at ufw is open.

Which mistake I make?
Is the port 5901 right to use?

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that you are doing ssh port-forwarding, I understand xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5901 is not directly accessible from your Windows machine.

Can you try to go in via VNC viewer (Windows) with `localhost:5901`, after setting up ssh as follows ?

```
ssh -X -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p2222
```

Comment: Yes, have tried.
I am using ssh with:
ssh -l user -L 5901:localhost:5901 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 2222
logged in.
Via VNC (Windows) with localhost:5901 I get the following error message:
"The connection was terminated unexpectedly".

Comment: Have you tries `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` ?

Comment: yes, and if I press enter, I get the following error massage in my console: "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"